# Migrating from TFS to VSTS - Database Warnings: Ignore or Abort

Tags: database, azure, tfs, migration, azure-devops

We are planning a migration from an on-premises TFS instance to VSTS very shortly. Ahead of the migration, we run the pre-requisite Validation task and obtained the following Database warnings from the TFS Migrator log report:

***[Warning@18:33:45.726] The database is currently 152GBs. This is above the recommended size of 150GBs to use the DACPAC import method. 
Please see the following page to learn how to import using a SQL Azure VM: https://aka.ms/VSTSImportLargeCollection
[Warning@18:33:45.726] The largest table size is currently 139GBs. This is above the recommended size of 20GBs to use the DACPAC import method. 
Please see the following page to learn how to import using a SQL Azure VM: https://aka.ms/VSTSImportLargeCollection***

We are confident we can carry out some further housekeeping tasks to bring the database size to below the 150GB threshold, however we 
are not so sure about successfully reducing the largest table from its current size of 139GB to within the recommended size of 20GB.

My question therefore is, considering the above is reported as a warning and not an error, can we still proceed with the DACPAC import 
method for our migration, as the SQL Azure VM option has been ruled out completely by the business due to financial reasons. If so, what risks do we potentially face?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if TfsMigrator warns that you can't use the DACPAC method then you will have to import using the SQL Azure VM method.